# SQL Query - Get Most Recent Document Version URL for Each Document

Tags: sql, sql-server, greatest-n-per-group

How can i list out all of the documents displaying the LATEST version URL for each document only?

**NOTE :** Document Versions in which a document can have multiple versions.  Versions are labelled by version number 1, 2, 3, etc...

[image]

I have the following sql but not sure if is the most efficient way to do it.

```
select * 
from documents d
inner join documentVersions v on d.id = v.documentid
                              and v.id = (select top (1) v2.id 
                                          from documentversions v2 
                                          where v2.documentid = v.documentid 
                                          order by v2.version desc)
```

Thanks

Comment: Why can't you use the `CreatedDate` column from the `DocumentVersions` table instead of `TOP(1)`, since the latest version will always be created at the last?

Comment: or `max(Version)` in the sub-query?

Answer (score 0):

Updated :
As per your question: This is enough to satisfy your requirement.

```
    select t2.documentid,t1.name,max(t2.version) 
    from 
    documents t1 JOIN documentversions t2 
    on t1.id=t2.documentid group by t1.name,t2.documentid 
    order by t2.version,t2.createddate desc.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the blow query, this will return the latest version of each document.

```
Select  *
from    documents d
    inner join  (
        select  *,
            ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by v.documentid order by v.version desc) as row_no
        from    documentVersions v
    ) as v2 on  d.id = v2.documentid and v2.row_no = 1
```

there are lot of other ways to do the same.
Eg;- If you update the `Document.ModifiedDate` as same as `DocumentVersions.CratedDate` while you create each `DocumentVersions`, then you can simply query this

```
Select * 
from documents d
inner join documentVersions v
 on d.id = v.documentid
 and d.ModifiedDate = v.CratedDate
```

Comment: or you can also store the latest version number in Document table.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
select * into #DocumentVersions from  (
select 1 DocumentId, 2 Version, '12 ' Url  union all
select 1 DocumentId, 1 Version, '31 ' Url  union all
select 1 DocumentId, 3 Version, '33 ' Url  union all
select 2 DocumentId, 9 Version, '11 ' Url  union all
select 2 DocumentId, 1 Version, '12 ' Url  union all
select 3 DocumentId, 1 Version, '31 ' Url  
) x
select * into #documents from  (
           select 1 id  union all
            select 2 id  union all
             select 3 id 
) y
Select  *
from    #documents documents
    left join  (
        select  *,
            ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by documentid order by version desc) as top_row
        from    #documentVersions
    ) as documentVersions on  documents.id = documentid 
    where top_row = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

It will be better instead of having `ModifiedDate` in your `Documents` table (or among with) to have `VersionID` column which is matching the `ID` of the `DocumentsVersions` table.

This can be done easily in the routine which is inserting the new version of the document. Using `OUTPUT` clause when multiple records are inserted for different documents or using `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` - both techniques will give you the `ID` of the inserted record(s) of the `DocumentsVersions`table - then, just update the `Documents` table.

We are using such `VersionID` columns where we have documents which are constantly updated. Having such column is going to simplify your query and improve performance as you are going to perform `INNER JOIN`:

```
SELECT *
FROM Documents A
INNER JOIN DocumentsVersions B
    ON A.[VersionID] = B.[ID];
```